# Button not working after Javascript function call

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below javascript SlideIn function is working fine. But, why I am not able to click the "Click me" button after slide in effect? This button is getting disabled after the slide in. Please help.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onClick="slideIn('check');"></a>
<div id="check">
    <input type="submit" value="Click me">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function slideIn(el) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition="left 0.3s linear 0s";
    elem.style.left="0%";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your element is being overlaid by another one after the transition, but you haven't provided enough context to provide any further help.

Comment: I can not reproduce you problem. Please, add an example (http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. There was problem in my CSS. I was using `position: relative` instead of `absolute`.

```
div#check {
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -400px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```